# Flask development server with X-Sendfile

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug, x-sendfile

I have a Flask application that will run under Apache in production. I have some static files, but they require authenticated access. So using X-Sendfile seemed reasonable to speed up the file delivery after authentication:

```
flaskapp = flask.Flask()
flaskapp.use_x_sendfile = True
```

Then where I'm generating the response:

```
return flask.send_file(filepath)
```

It seems to work fine under Apache. The problem is when I run the development server:

```
# Use SharedDataMiddleware to deliver JS, CSS, icons, etc.
flaskapp.wsgi_app = SharedDataMiddleware(flaskapp.wsgi_app, {'/static': '/path/to/static'})
flaskapp.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

When I run it this way with `use_x_sendfile = True`, the X-Sendfile header shows up in the actual response and an empty file (0 byte) is delivered to the client. Turning off X-Sendfile (and forcing the browser to discard the cached file) fixes the issue, so it seems the Werkzeug server Flask runs isn't processing the X-Sendfile header. Is there a way to enable the development server to process X-Sendfile, or am I forced to turn this off during development?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flask documentation mentions that the [server must support](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.use_x_sendfile) the `X-Sendfile`, and werkzeug's dev server doesn't (there's no mention anywhere in the documentation and a grep through werkzeug's source for `sendfile` returned no matches).

It wouldn't probably be too hard to add this behaviour to the server, but I'm not really sure if supporting such advanced features is a priority for a developement server.

Btw, as additional keyword arguments to [`run`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.run) are passed through to werkzeug's [`run_simple`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/serving/#werkzeug.serving.run_simple), you don't need to create the middleware yourself, you can just use:

```
flaskapp.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, static_files={'/static': '/path/to/static'})
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I got the `SharedDataMiddleware` stuff from Flask's site somewhere.