# Flask static files error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

Tags: python, flask

I have a working python 3.9 Flask app.  The latest Pycharm is my IDE.  Yesterday I created a new app with a very similar structure.  The old app runs and finds/loads all static content just as expected when run through the PyCharm debugger or from the command line with `flask run`.

The new app will "run" from PyCharm or `flask run`.  It loads the main/home blueprint and serves the correct template.  What it does not do is serve any css or js resources in the `static` folder.  Rather, it tries to load them but each resource in the Brave developer tools window has the message:

`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH`

I have surveyed the file sizes for each css and js file.  I have matched the lengths against the developer tools "network" tab response information and it looks like all the sizes match.

I have tried this with FireFox and it just says:

`Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/LIB/jquery/jquery.min.js”.`

and the other resources.

I have deleted and recreated the `node_modules` and the `.idea` dirs.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Sigh, my problem was with setting the `USE_X_SENDFILE` Flask config variable.  The dev server does not support it and honestly I don't know why I even included it.  Removing it fixed my issues.

Thanks entirely to this post:
[Flask development server with X-Sendfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17434687/flask-development-server-with-x-sendfile)